Error installing newer version of Git after CentOS 7 end of life in 2024
After CentOS 7 end of life, the yum update command results in an error.
I deleted the files:

CentOS-Base.repo
CentOS-CR. repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo
CentOS-Media.repo
CentOS-Sources.repo
CentOS-x86_64-kernel.repo

in the /etc/yum.repos.d directory
then I added 1 repo
[base]
name=CentOS-7.9 - Base
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[updates]
name=CentOS-7.9 - Updates
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/updates/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[extra]
name=CentOS-7.9 - Extras
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/extras/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

yum update was successful, but I want to install git version > 2
based on post from here
but error when yum install git
Error: Package: git-core-2.43.0-1.ep7.x86_64 (endpoint)
 Requires: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-Git-2.43.0-1.ep7.noarch (endpoint)
 Requirements: perl(Error)
Error: Package: git-2.43.0-1.ep7.x86_64 (endpoint)
 Requirements: perl(Term::ReadKey)

Is there a repo solution for CentOS 7 in 2024?

The information you need is here:  https://blog.centos.org/2023/04/end-dates-are-coming-for-centos-stream-8-and-centos-linux-7/

No. Do not use EL7 anymore, including CentOS 7.
In the year 2024, your latest Red Hat distros are EL9 or Fedora 40. Build a new host based on those.
CentOS vault is not a solution for an end of life distro. Vault's older and unmaintained packages are archived to make it possible to upgrade to supported software.
